# Changing leaflet markercluster icon color, inheriting the rest of the default CSS properties

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, markerclusterer

So, I'm trying to change the color of the markercluster icons in a leaflet map. I just want to change the color inheriting the rest of the default properties (i.e., shape, text properties, etc...).

In this an [example](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html), there is something similar to what I want to get, but they define a brand new CSS class without using the default icons styling. What I need is something like this but with custom colors:

[image]

I do know that I have to customize `iconCreateFunction`. I'm trying in this way:

CSS

```
.foo { background-color: red;}
.bar { background-color: blue;}
```

JavaScript

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        // here there is a piece code that determines the value of the variable 'class_name' is either foo or bar
        return L.divIcon({ className: "marker-cluster-medium "+class_name});
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, that solution does not work and leads to a ugly icon rendering.

How can I just change the color of the default markercluster icons?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `iconCreateFunction` should look some thing like this...

```
    iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
     var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
     var c = ' marker-cluster-';
     if (childCount < 10) {
       c += 'small';
     } 
     else if (childCount < 100) {
       c += 'medium';
     } 
     else {
       c += 'large';
     }
    
     return new L.divIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', 
      className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
    }
```

...and change CSS to something like this...

```
    .marker-cluster-small {
    background-color: rgba(218, 94, 94, 0.6);
    }
    .marker-cluster-small div {
    background-color: rgba(226, 36, 36, 0.6);
    }
    .marker-cluster-medium {
    background-color: rgba(241, 211, 87, 0.6);
    }
    .marker-cluster-medium div {
    background-color: rgba(240, 194, 12, 0.6);
    }

    .marker-cluster-large {
    background-color: rgba(253, 156, 115, 0.6);
    }
    .marker-cluster-large div {
    background-color: rgba(241, 128, 23, 0.6);
    }
```

See the below plunker for a complete working example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/GvDbB1rzIZ4bvIkQjM0p?p=preview

Comment: Hello, in that way you do not have the default bubbles icons. I added an image in the original question for clarifying.

Comment: @floatingpurr do you have the link of the working example of the image you placed

Comment: Yes, you can find an example [here](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html). That's the default behavior of the library.

Comment: Did you ever find how to maintain the default bubbles, etc, changing only the icon colo(u)r?

Answer (score 4):

It's so simple just add CSS in your global.css or style.css file

```
.marker-cluster-small {
  background-color: #49afa5 !important;
}

.marker-cluster-small div {
  background-color: #1c9489 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: That would affect ***all*** cluster groups.  The OP wants one to be default and the other to have different colo(u)rs, to be able to differentiate.